# Merge [textformat] and [text-formatting]

Tags: discussion, status-declined, tags, synonym-request

[textformat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/textformat) contains 29 questions and has no excerpt or wiki 
[text-formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/text-formatting) contains 313 questions and also lacks an excerpt and wiki

Tag usage is similar, to indicate questions are regarding the formatting of text.

I propose we merge [textformat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/textformat) into [text-formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/text-formatting), as that is the bigger tag. Personally lack the score to propose the synonym, so here we go.

Comment: This sounds reasonable on first blush, but we do need to take care to ensure that “textformat” is not the name of a library, control, or other product. That would make it not a synonym of the generic term, and indicate a cleanup/disambiguation, rather than a merge.

Comment: @CodyGray I scanned every single question of textformat. It spans across all languages. No question excerpt suggested it being a specific product/library/module etc.

Comment: As pointed out by @BhargavRao scanning the question excerpts wasn't enough. Please refer to his answer for details.

Comment: There were 18 questions in the [textformat] tag, that weren't related to the actionscript text formatting, cleaned them up. Writing a wiki for the tag would be a good finish to this.

Answer (score 8):

As Cody mentions in a comment, usually, whenever you see a tag like [textformat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/textformat), we need to make sure that it is not related to any library function in a particular language (TextFormat). Finding out this information can be made simpler by looking at the related tags of that particular tag. If the tag is being used a lot with another given language/tool tag, then it probably might be a function in that particular language.

In this particular case, the most related tag ([actionscript-3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/actionscript-3)) was present on 10 questions out of 29. There seems to be a certain [TextFormat class in actionscript 3](https://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/text/TextFormat.html). When I checked the 10 questions, most of them seem to be about this class. This needs to be discussed with the users of [actionscript-3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/actionscript-3) before the creation of a synonym, about whether it needs to be a separate tag or not. Also, a quick google search returned [this class in protobuf](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/java/com/google/protobuf/TextFormat), however no questions along with the [java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java) tag were related to this class, so we can rule out this option.

Once this is resolved, we can merge the two tags, as they seem to be used interchangeably, in the other cases.

Comment: Lesson learned: reading the Q excerpts just isn't enough.